# Upgrading Products.kupu from unknown profile version

Tags: plone

I'm trying to upgrade the Kupu to version 1.4.16. I updated the versions.cfg in my buildout but in the portal_setup tools the following is shown:

```
The profile "kupu:default" is currently upgraded to version unknown.

The filesystem version for the "kupu:default" profile is currently 1.4.16. 

No upgrade available.
```

So I don't have a handle for upgrade.

Any ideas?

Best regards,

Manuel.

Comment: perhaps there is no upgrade step to run for the new version.

Comment: But I'm worried about the fact that it reports an unknown profile and a defined (1.4.16) profile in the FS. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because profile version is not the same version as egg version.

egg version is specified in the setup.py file and is the version you can find on pypi.
For example: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.kupu/1.4.16

Profile version is an integer that is specified in Products.kupu/Products/kupu/profiles/default/metadata.xml and represent the version of the 'installer' profile. It means one version of profile can be the same throw many eggs version (if install doesn't need to be updated).

So the question become why the version of the profile is 'unknown' ?

Because the metadata.xml doesn't provide any version number.

By the way when a package is updated you have to check if the package provide an upgrade step. If it doesn't there is one of the two reason:

- The package is not well maintained so you have to upgrade yourself ... (cook resources, ...)
- The package doesn't need to upgrade the install (mean only python code has been updated, so just restart)